# Can someone explain how cordova custom plugins get called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

So I made my own iOS plugin. And it is not getting called. So I am thinking that I do not understand how it all really works. The documentation is not being helpful to me for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a custom PhoneGap plugin for iOS.use these steps [example](http://moduscreate.com/building-a-custom-phonegap-plugin-for-ios/)